# hasManyThrough for 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I am stuck concerning the method **HasManyThrough**. In my view/cars/index.php I would like to get id, matriculation, name (fk_serie), name_mark.
I have a error message "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'marks.fk_serie' inconnu dans on clause"?

I have in fact 3 tables:
the first is named **cars** and I have 3 fields id, matriculation, fk_serie.

My second table is named **series**, I have 3 fields which are id, name, fk_mark.

My last table is named **marks**, I have 2 fields id, name_mark.

I know to join the table **cars** towards **series** or **series** towards **marks** however I don't understand how to do the junction between the table **cars** and the table **marks**.

First question, I must to create a fk_mark on the table **cars** ?

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('matriculation', 25);
            $table->integer('fk_serie')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('fk_serie')->references('id')->on('serie');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The others tables

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('series', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 30);
            $table->integer('fk_mark')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('fk_mark')->references('id')->on('mark');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('marks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name_mark', 30);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Second question: is it my models are OK ? please.

**Model Car**

```
class Car extends Model
{
    //
    public function serie(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Serie', 'fk_serie');
    }

    public function mark()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Serie',
            'App\Mark',
            'fk_serie', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'fk_mark', // Foreign key on users table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
    }
}
```

**Model Serie**

```
class Serie extends Model
{
    //
    public function mark(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mark', 'fk_mark');
    }
}
```

**Model Mark**

```
class Mark extends Model
{
    //

}
```

Third question: is it my loop is ok according you ?

In my **view/cars/index.php** I have this:

```
<tr>
   <th>Matriculation</th>
   <th>Serie car</th>
   <th>Mark car</th>
</tr>
</thead>
@foreach($cars as $car)
<tr>
   <td> {{$car->matriculation}}</td>
    <td> {{$car->serie->name}}</td>
    <td> {{$car->mark->name_mark}}</td>
etc...
```

Thank you for your help.

Overview screenshot below
[image]
[image]

**CarController**

```
class CarController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $cars = Car::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.cars.index', compact('cars'))
                  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
    }


}
```

**Edit: It's OK thank you a lot Lucas Piazzi.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between **Car** and **Mark** is wrong, the HasManyThrought relation should be on the Mark model, try this:

**Car** model:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    //
    public function serie(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Serie', 'fk_serie');
    }
}
```

**Mark** model:

```
public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Car',
            'App\Serie',
            'fk_mark', 
            'fk_serie',
            'id', 
            'id' 
        );
    }
public function series()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Serie','fk_mark');
   }
```

You could also access all cars with the [Has many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship in your Mark model, if you want.

Take a look at this piece of the docs:

> The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the name of the intermediate model.
>
> Typical Eloquent foreign key conventions will be used when performing the relationship's queries. If you would like to customize the keys of the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments to the hasManyThrough method. The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model. The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model. The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument is the local key of the intermediate model:

You're missing the inverse relationship in your models:

**Serie** Model:

```
class Serie extends Model
{
    public function mark(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mark', 'fk_mark');
    }

    public function cars(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Car', 'fk_serie');
    }

}
```

Answering your question:

No, you **don't need** to create a `fk_mark` in your `cars` table, If you want the Mark name that belongs to the car just do this:

In your **view**

```
<tr>
   <th>Matriculation</th>
   <th>Serie car</th>
   <th>Mark car</th>
</tr>
@foreach($cars as $car)
<tr>
   <td> {{$car->matriculation}}</td>
    <td> {{$car->serie->name}}</td> // or {{$car->series()->first()->name}}
    <td> {{$car->serie->mark->mark_name}}</td> // or {{$car->series()->first()->marks()->first()->name_mark}}
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb you my friend, do you have any idea of the creation of an edit / update in the controller with 2 models?
Sorry again to abuse your time.

Comment: You asked a question? if you did, please send me the link so i can help

Comment: Hello Lucas, I am really stuck for 2 days, can you try to help me? Please, thanks

Comment: Hey man, send me the link with your new question. Maybe i can help.

Comment: Thank you Lucas; here is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860818/dropdown-validate-2-items-on-3-only/56860903#56860903

Comment: I don't know if you understand my problem? :-(