# DropDown: Validate 2 items on 3 only

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, if-statement

I have 2 tables, the first is `Students` with 3 fields (name, firstname, fk_diploma).Then, my second table is named `Diplomas` and there is 1 field named (type_diploma).

For information, I have 3 values in my field `type_diploma`:

```
1) DiplomaA
2) DiplomaB
3) DiplomaC
```

In my validate system, I want the `DiplomaA` or `DiplomaB` to be validated but not the `DiplomaC`, I must have an error message.

For example: *** "Sorry, you do not have the skills for the diplomaC."**

Do you have an idea of how I can do that ?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {    
      $diploma = Diploma::select('type_diploma')->where('id',$request->fk_diploma)->get();
      if($diploma->type_diploma != 'DiplomaC')  
      {
      $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:200',
            'fk_diploma' => 'required'
        ]);
       }

       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->where('fk_diploma', $request->get('fk_diploma'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('error', 'duplicate');

        }   

    }
```

My model **Diploma**

```
class Diploma extends Model
{
    protected  $fillable = ['type_diploma'];


    public function diplomas(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Student', 'fk_diploma');
    }


}
```

Model **Student**

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected  $fillable = ['name', 'firstname', 'fk_diploma'];


    public function diplomas(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Diploma' , 'fk_diploma');
    }
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share your dateRequest class?

Comment: @Lucas Piazzi: I have edited my first message, thank Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to do it, but its the only one i could think right now:

1) change the type of your request to `public function store(Request $request)`

2) Do this in your function:

```
public function store(dateRequest $request)
{    
      $diploma = Diploma::select('type_diploma')->where('id',$request->fk_diploma)->get();
      if($diploma->type_diploma != 'DiplomaA' && $diploma->type_diploma != 'DiplomaB')  
      {
      $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:200',
            'fk_diploma' => 'required'
        ]);
       }

       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->where('fk_diploma', $request->get('fk_diploma'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('error', 'duplicate');

        }   

}
```

Comment: Almost, I have a error message `Property [type_diploma] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: i updated my answer, you just need to access the type_diploma attribute from the diplomas table. Make sure this is the right name

Comment: I have edited my first message. My problem is the line 74 ?

Comment: Perhaps my problem is the Model?

Comment: coud you dd() the diploma variable?

Comment: I have changed `)->get();` with `)->first();` . I dont have error message. However, the value 'DiplomaC'  does not block in my form...

Comment: I think i dont understand your question. You can't select the DiplomaC on the form?

Comment: It works like this -> `public function store(Request $request)
    {    
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|min:3',
                'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:200',
                'fk_diploma' => 'required'
             ]);
        $diploma = Diploma::select('type_diploma')->where('id',$request->fk_diploma)->first();
        if($diploma->type_diploma != 'DiplomaA' && $diploma->type_diploma != 'DiplomaB')  {
         return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('error', 'Vous êtes entrée!');
            }`

Comment: Thank you a lot. You are the best... ^^

Comment: glad i could help again, friend!

Comment: I can ask you a little question please?

Comment: Thank you, it's here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581930/column-not-found-1054-field-field-email-unknown-in-where thank you a lot

Comment: excuse me for disturbing you, can you help me here please?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779665/duplicate-system-on-two-forms/57782393#57782393

I am really stuck :-(

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'fk_diploma' => 'required|not_in:XXX',
]);
```

XXX - id of the diploma you don't want to accept

Comment: I have tried this but I always have the even problem. "DiplomaC' is not is not blocked. `public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|min:3',
                'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:200',
                'fk_diploma' => 'required|not_in:DiplomaC'
        ]);
        `