# Column not found: 1054 Field Field 'email' unknown in where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 rubrics for now.

[image]

When, I login in the rubric `Student`with the email `test.gmail.com` I can see my informations private

[image]

Then, I LOGIN in the rubric `Feedback` always with the email `test.gmail.com` I have like error message:

`SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Field Field 'email' unknown in where (SQL: select count (*) as aggregate from`returns`where` email`= test@gmail.com)`

my fields on the table `Feedbacks` are:

`protected  $fillable = ['user_id','instruction', 'description', 'fk_eleve'];`

My function index() is the following:

```
public function index(Request $request)

{   
    $user = $request->user();

    $feedbacks = Feedback::query()
    ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('email', $user->email);
    })
    ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
     $query->join('eleves', 'feedbacks.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->where('eleves.nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
     })
    ->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: hey friend, just to remind you. You need to put in the fillable array which model attributes you want to make mass assignable.  Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to add the email column to your fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id','instruction', 'description', 'fk_eleve', 'email'];
```

Did you further create a proper migration for this, like does the table have the column email?

Comment: Ok, thank you, In fact I have already an email address via my foreign key eleve. It's no possible to retrieve via my table student?

Comment: @user11124425 it is you would need to call the email using the foreign key